# Group with $a=a^{-1}$ for all $a\in G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be a group, and suppose that $a= {a^{-1}}$ for every $a\in G$. Prove that $G$ is Abelian.

I know that I need to prove that ${a^{-1}}$ = *a* and use right multiplication. I also know that I need to declare *a*, *b* $\in$ *G* and go from there, but I'm confused when I get to

(${a^{-1}}$${b^{-1}}$) = *ab*.

Comment: The commutator is 1.

Answer (score 7):

$G$ is abelian if for every $a$, $b \in G$ we have that $ab=ba$. So

$$ab= a^{-1}b^{-1}= (ba)^{-1}=ba.$$

Can you see that $ a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}$?

If not, here is the explanation:

Since $G$ is a group then $(ba)^{-1}$ exists and it is such that $ba(ba)^{-1}=e$, where $e$ is the nautral element in your group. We also know that the inverse is unique.

Note that $baa^{-1}b^{-1}=e,$ thus $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ has to be that inverse, i.e., 
 $(ba)^{-1}= a^{-1}b^{-1}$